# Full-text personalized search product

Tags: search, full-text-search, nlp, information-retrieval

What full-text search technology is out there to support full-text *personalized* search?

For instance, contact search in your webmail provider of choice: it's full text but only searches your personal contacts and not the entire universe of contacts.

There are countless full-text search packages out there but I don't know how you could use most full-text search packages such that every user only sees a small subset of the universe of documents.

Comment: Google personalized search does some of that, doesn't it? I'm not aware of product where you can just have it lurk on your system and interface with all your accounts + stuff though. I guess you could write something like this with lucene and maybe a plugin for your browser?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of email, it's simple: use any popular search toolkit and build an index per user. It's simple because the indexes shouldn't overlap, or you'd be violating users' privacy. Also, overlap might skew figures like IDF. (You might be tempted to index emails sent to multiple users only once, but the security and privacy implications of that aren't worth it. Disk is cheap.)

If a *common* collection of documents should be indexed for personalized search, you're on your own, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend build lucene index of all contacts with special fields like contact_list_id, usage_freuency. At time of search for each user add their specific params ie  text:"John smith" AND contact_list_id:"$current_user_id" order by usege_freuency. In this case you will have optimized index all data compressed in one place and it is also personilized by field like usage_freuency or more robust rank. Think about index as DB with highly effective search by text.